# Change URL string to hyperlink in C# ASP.NET MVC in View

Tags: c#, html, razor, hyperlink, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to convert the URL into short hyperlinks. I am using .NET Core MVC. How can I display the string of link as hyperlink in this view? I want to do this in View and not in Controller side.

`message.MessageText` contains messages which may or may not contain URLs. The regex part is already working, it matches with any URL on the message. When the page loads the hyperlink is displayed as string and not as link. Is it possible to do this way from View or do I have to add the code to controller?

```
<html>
    <div>
        @{
            Regex rx = new Regex(@"^(https:|http:|www\.)\S*");
            var matches = rx.Matches(message.MessageText);
            string URLMessage = Regex.Replace(message.MessageText,
                                              @"(https:|http:|www\.)\S*",
                                              delegate (Match match)
                                              {
                                                string v = match.ToString();
                                                return "<a href='" + v + "' target='_blank' title='" + v + "'>123</a>";
                                              });
        }                                            

        @URLMessage                                             
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Html.Raw(string)` to render html string :

```
@Html.Raw(URLMessage)
```